MetalLB LoadBalancer issue on Raspberry Pi Kubernetes Cluster
I'm trying to run a Kubernetes cluster on a single Raspberry Pi for a personal use and so far have installed MetalLB along with Nginx to provide LoadBalancer services.
This is the guide I'm trying to follow (this will be my ultimate goal as well): https://greg.jeanmart.me/2020/04/13/install-and-configure-a-kubernetes-cluster-w/
It required some tweaking, but because I really suck at networking I got to the point where majority of my pods are running (besides the one with the duplicated port), but my load balancing is defo wrong and for some reason metallb-speaker shares the same IP with my master (192.168.0.17).
SVC:
NAMESPACE     NAME                                               TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
default       kubernetes                                         ClusterIP      10.43.0.1       <none>        443/TCP                      115m
default       test-service                                       LoadBalancer   10.43.115.189   <pending>     8080:31117/TCP               77m
kube-system   kube-dns                                           ClusterIP      10.43.0.10      <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP       115m
kube-system   metallb-webhook-service                            ClusterIP      10.43.131.11    <none>        443/TCP                      94m
kube-system   metrics-server                                     ClusterIP      10.43.194.117   <none>        443/TCP                      115m
kube-system   nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   10.43.3.246     <pending>     80:30127/TCP,443:32595/TCP   83m
kube-system   nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP      10.43.172.94    <none>        443/TCP                      83m
kube-system   traefik                                            LoadBalancer   10.43.212.63    <pending>     80:32404/TCP,443:32029/TCP   114m

PODS:
NAME                                                          READY   STATUS      RESTARTS        AGE
coredns-7647b64657-8dhzx                                      1/1     Running     3 (2m24s ago)   71m
helm-install-traefik-crd-4xwkc                                0/1     Completed   0               115m
helm-install-traefik-vfp4h                                    0/1     Completed   1               115m
local-path-provisioner-59c9dd488-dqh8j                        1/1     Running     3 (2m24s ago)   71m
metallb-controller-8dcbdd89b-rhfpg                            1/1     Running     1 (2m24s ago)   9m1s
metallb-speaker-qtbn2                                         4/4     Running     4 (2m24s ago)   9m1s
metrics-server-5d85bcbc8b-ktslg                               1/1     Running     3 (2m24s ago)   71m
nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller-645dc78648-g52mx       1/1     Running     3 (2m24s ago)   71m
svclb-nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller-3123b3bd-d8tk7   0/2     Pending     0               84m
svclb-test-service-d146cfdd-lszw2                             1/1     Running     2 (2m24s ago)   54m
svclb-traefik-cbb30ddb-xntlf                                  2/2     Running     6 (2m24s ago)   115m
traefik-ff6698b4d-vxfkw                                       1/1     Running     3 (2m24s ago)   71m

METALLB:
NAME                                 READY   STATUS    RESTARTS        AGE   IP             NODE          NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
metallb-controller-8dcbdd89b-rhfpg   1/1     Running   1 (5m38s ago)   12m   10.42.0.40     raspberrypi   <none>           <none>
metallb-speaker-qtbn2                4/4     Running   4 (5m38s ago)   12m   192.168.0.17   raspberrypi   <none>           <none>

metallb-config.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  namespace: kube-system
  name: config
data:
  config: |
    address-pools:
    - name: default
      protocol: layer2
      addresses:
      - 192.168.0.240-192.168.0.250


Verified that no other devices on my network are using IPs in the range 192.168.0.240-192.168.0.250
Reapplied the MetalLB configuration.
Restarted MetalLB pods.
Checked service annotations for any specific IP assignments.
Checked the logs from the MetalLB controller and speaker and it seems that there is an issue with IP assignment for the services. Specifically, the error message:

"error":"assigned IP not allowed by config","ips":["192.168.0.17"],"level":"error","msg":"IP allocated by controller not allowed by config"

How can I configure MetalLB to correctly assign IPs from the specified range and avoid using the node's IP? Is there any additional configuration I might be missing? I'll appreciate any assistance, thanks in advance!

Of course it has the same IP address you only have a single device. Does the guide use a single device or are you altering what you did to support the fact you only have one device in the cluster, which does not really make it a cluster.

Apologies, I should have been more specific. Currently there's only 1 device (I'm planning to add more in the future so that's why I've used this terminology) in my setup. Guide is focusing on multiple workers, but for my current purpose I want to build only 1 host which will be serving as master and worker.

So you would use the same ip address. Cluster of workers make more sense on a single machine

Noted, and what about the external IPs not being assigned to any of the services despite of specifing range under metallb config?

When you say external you mean, external to the cluster, or external as in internet IP addresses rather than the intranet addresses your cluster would be aware of?  Why are you using 192.168.0.240-192.168.0.250 instead of 10.43.0.240-10.43.0.250?

I simply followed the guide "The IPs range 192.168.0.240-192.168.0.250 is used to constitute a pool of virtual IP addresses.". When it comes to external IPs "Nginx service is deployed in LoadBalancer mode, you can observe MetalLB allocates a virtual IP (column EXTERNAL-IP) to Nginx with the command } From you local machine, you can try to externally access Nginx via the LoadBalancer IP (in my case http://192.168.0.240) and it should return the following message “404 not found” because nothing is deployed yet."
In my case nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller is constantly in  state.

Except based on what I can tell you not using 192.168.0.x subnet. Those IP addresses are an example. Try using the subnet you are actually using.

Pardon me for a potentially dumb question. How can you tell I'm not using 192.168.0.x subnet? I haven't change anything (because I don't know how) and (again) according to the guide everything looks fine, except for the missing external IP.
Example:
nginx-ingress-controller   LoadBalancer   10.43.253.188   192.168.0.240   80:30423/TCP,443:32242/TCP   92s   app=nginx-ingress,component=controller,release=nginx-ingress
